# Can a static method be overridden in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding, static-methods, final

I was told that `static` methods are implicitly `final` and therefore can't be overridden. Is that true?

1. Can someone give a better example of overriding a static method?
2. If static methods are just class methods, what is the real use of having them?

Comment: No, they can't be overridden. They are associated with the class, not with an object.

Comment: for the real use: you can call a static method without the class instance.

Comment: Thanks. I understand [what a static method is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4124118/2061309), best example given by SLaks. So for my question about overriding a static method (if bydefault is it final, not user make it final) - does it mean no subclass of this class which holds a static can define a static method with the same signature?

Comment: btw it seems like a question asked in my exam paper :P

Comment: I don't think you are my class mate :D but happy to be. PS: If notice the novice flavour of my question, yes I am in the phase of learning *proper theory* - I realized without them I can only write algo-codes but not able to properly explain :)

Comment: The compiler itself could have tol you that `static members cannot be marked as virtual, override or abstract`

Comment: Maybe the best way to understand best usage is to look at how Microsoft has used them in the .Net Framework. Here's a link to MSDN API's on System.String. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Notice the methods with red S, this indicates the method is static. 

Operator overloads are always done as static methods.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(1) Static methods cannot be overridden, they can however be hidden using the 'new' keyword. Mostly overriding methods means you reference a base type and want to call a derived method. Since static's are part of the type and aren't subject to vtable lookups that doesn't make sense.

E.g. statics cannot do:

```
public class Foo { 
    public virtual void Bar() { ... }
}
public class Bar : Foo {
    public override void Bar() { ... }
}

// use:
Foo foo = new Bar(); // make an instance
foo.Bar(); // calls Bar::Bar
```

Because statics don't work on instances, you always specify Foo.Bar or Bar.Bar explicitly. So overriding has no meaning here (try expressing it in code...).

(2) There are different usages for static methods. For example, it's being used in the Singleton pattern to get a single instance of a type. Another example is 'static void Main', which is the main access point in your program.

Basically you use them whenever you don't want or cannot create an object instance before using it. For example, when the static method creates the object.

**[update]**

A simple hiding example:

```
public class StaticTest
{
    public static void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Foo 1"); }
    public static void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("Bar 1"); }
}

public class StaticTest2 : StaticTest
{
    public new static void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Foo 2"); }
    public static void Some() { Foo(); Bar(); } // Will print Foo 2, Bar 1
}

public class TestStatic
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StaticTest2.Foo();
        StaticTest2.Some();
        StaticTest.Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note that if you make the classes `static`, you cannot do this. Static classes have to derive from `object`.

The main difference between this and inheritance is that the compiler can determine at compile-time which method to call when using static. If you have instances of objects, you need to do this at runtime (which is called a vtable lookup).

Comment: Thanks for giving me that example of overriding. Yes I am trying out in the code. So to get this right, 1) **we can sub-class a static class like any other non-static class**? 2) we can use static methods without overriding parent class static methods but hiding them using New keyword.

Comment: I added some more explanation and an example. (1) No you cannot sub-class a static class, but you can hide static members. (2) yes, you should try the second example, it tells how it behaves.

Comment: I get: `'Bar' member names cannot be the same as their enclosing types` if I apply your first example. `Bar.Bar ` can't even work.

Answer (score 7):

Well You can't override a static method. A static method can't be virtual, since it's not related to an instance of the class.

The "overridden" method in the derived class is actually a new method, unrelated to the one defined in the base class (hence the new keyword).

This is an important thing to understand: when types inherit from other types, they fulfil a common contract, whereas static types are not bound by any contract (from the pure OOP point of view). There's no technical way in the language to tie two static types together with an "inheritance" contract. If you would "override" the Log method in two different places.

If you think about overriding static methods it, it doesn't really make sense; in order to have virtual dispatch you need an actual instance of an object to check against.

A static method also can't implement an interface; if this class is implementing an IRolesService interface then I would contend that the method should not be static at all. It's better design to have an instance method, so you can swap out your MockRoleService with a real service when you're ready

Comment: Thanks. It's slightly bit up level for me to digest, but along the way I will get it :) PS: And I definitely want to be in your class in that case. Found [this post too in Java context.](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/can-static-methods-be-overridden/1)

Answer (score 6):

You don't override a static method. You hide it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196834/51) for more info.

Some reasons to use static methods:

1. They are a [little bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016750/51) than instance methods. Also see this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) which gives performance numbers to back this up (inlined static call avg 0.2 ns, static call avg 6.1ns, inlined instance call avg 1.1 ns, instance call avg 6.8 ns)
2. Less verbose to write out - don't need to instantiate a class to get to them (and instantiation can also affect performance)

Comment: I have no issues with instance methods. I learnt that `static` Class can't be instantiated. But you mentioned that "static methods is that it is instantiated only once in your app".. So I am confused now. Are you referring to `Using System.Math;` by saying static methods are instantiated? I have been using Math class members Math.Abs() multiple times in the same class without instantiating them even once. 1) So could you please clarify what you meant by ***"instantiating once"***? 2) Can a Static Class be sub-classes? Does it make sense to Sub-Class a static class?

Comment: see my edit. I shouldnt have used the term "instantiated" with a static method. more correct is to say that it is only created once.

Comment: All *methods* are only "created" once. Even non-static methods have only one copy of the code in existence (IL code which is created at compile-time and converted into machine code *once* at run-time). Do not confuse code and data! A non-static method is only *callable* via an instance of an object, but that is because of the hidden "this" pointer which is passed to it. The code itself is "static" in that it's fixed and singleton.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for the correction. I removed the offending section and updated answer