# C# Override static methods

Tags: c#, methods, overriding

I have the following classes and methods

```
public class X
{
    public static void M1(...)
    {
        ...
        var isSomething = M2(...);
        ...
    }

    public static bool M2(...) { ... }
}
```

I need to implement a new M2 method with same signature to be called in some ocasions.
To do this I was thinking to implement a new class Y extending X and override M2 method, so when I call Y.M1() I want to use y.M2().

```
public class Y : X
{
    public static [override] bool M2(...) { ... }
}
```

But static methods cannot be overriden.
Anyone has an advice how could I can do this?

Comment: It's kind of funny that you chose `X` and `Y` as your example class names because this is potentially an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Can you give us a little more context about what you are trying to do and *why* you want to do it this way?

Comment: That indeed sounds like you **actually** need something completely different, but just **assume** overriding a static method would be the solution. But without any further information about why you need this it´s hard to guess. Why not just make some condition and call either one method or the other one?

Comment: @cesarfaria Is `M2()` really required to be static? If not, just remove the `static` modifier. As long as this method doesn't need to be callable from other classes without a reference to an instance of `class X`, this is always possible. Otherwise, create a `virtual` wrapper for `M2()` and call it from `M1()`. Then override this one with a method that calls the other `M2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but as far as I understand your question, you want to change the behavior of `M1()`, which is inherited by class `Y`, by a different static method `M2()`. This isn't possible, if all methods involved are static, but you can yield the desired effect if you declare `M1()` as non-static. This might be done this way:

```
public class X
    {
    public Boolean M1 (Int32 x1)
        {
        return M2 (x1);
        }
    public virtual Boolean M2 (Int32 x2)
        {
        return M3 (x2);
        }
    public static Boolean M3 (Int32 x2)
        {
        return x2 >= 0;
        }
    }

public class Y : X
    {
    public override Boolean M2 (Int32 x2)
        {
        return M3 (x2);
        }
    public static new Boolean M3 (Int32 x2)
        {
        return x2 < 0;
        }
    }
```

Here's a test case:

```
Boolean fTest1 = new X ().M1 (1);
Boolean fTest2 = new Y ().M1 (1);

Console.Write ("{0} {1}", fTest1, fTest2);
```

This will output:

```
True False
```

So the wrapper method `M2()`, which calls the static method `M3()` in `X` is `virtual` and can be overridden in `Y`, calling a different static method `M3()`. Hence, if you're using an instance of the derived class `Y`, the call to `M2()` inside the inherited method `M1()` is directed to the `M2()` method overridden inside `Y`, which in turn calls the other `M3()`, with the desired change of behavior - in this example, the result is the inverse boolean value.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that I could use only static methods to do that, like Risto M sugested in previous answer, but is not working.

Comment: @cesarfaria Yes, the problem here is that static methods can be hidden, but not overridden. That's two different things. You need an override to get the call directed to the inherited class, and hence a virtual method must be involved somewhere. Frankly, I had a similar problem myself not long ago, and wished that I could override a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods cannot be overridden. [Dynamic binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) is possible only with object instances.

You can "hide" static methods from base class with `new` keyword as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828401/5789864). In your case, you can write your `Y.M2()` with  following style:

```
public class Y : X
{
    public static new bool M2(...) { ... }
}
```

Keep in mind that this style is not same as *normal* virtual non-static method overriding. With non-static method overriding, method binding is done run-time depending on actual object type. static-method binding is done in compile-time.

Comment: The `new` keyword just gets rid of the warning that hiding an inherited member might not be intended. It doesn't solve the problem stated in the question, however - that is, calling `Y.M1()` will still call `X.M2()`, and not `Y.M2()`, because hiding is not the same as overriding.