# C# Generics Specialization

Tags: c#, generics, specialization

I created a specialization for a generic like code below:

```
public class BaseGeneric<T>
{
    public static T DoStuff()
        => default;
}

public class SpecializedFromBaseGeneric : BaseGeneric<int>
{
    public static new int DoStuff()
        => 789;
}
```

Now to call the `DoStuff()` method I would like to use `var result = BaseGeneric<int>.DoStuff();`

When I run this code, `result` is `0` instead of `789`. The debugger shows that the call will enter the `DoStuff()` from `public class BaseGeneric<T>` instead of `SpecializedFromBaseGeneric`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Later edit**

I also tried to create specialization in the below format but that does not even compile:

```
public class BaseGeneric<T> where T : int
{
    public static T DoStuff()
        => 789;
}
```

I want to do several specializations and use the call similar to the one specified above for `int` data type `BaseGeneric<int>.DoStuff()`. And for each specialization use the same syntax where only data type is changed but different implementation is used (eg: for string that would be `BaseGeneric<string>.DoStuff()`). How to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Well you wrote `BaseGeneric<int>.DoStuff()`, so *that* method is called. If you want  the method in `SpecializedFromBaseGeneric`, write `SpecializedFromBaseGeneric.DoStuff()`.

Comment: @Sweeper that makes sense but actually I want to do several specializations and use the call similar to this int one `BaseGeneric<int>.DoStuff();` for each specialization (eg: `BaseGeneric<string>.DoStuff();`)

Comment: C# generics are not C++ templates. There's no specialization. You write one piece of code only that has to work with all types which meet any type constraints for their type parameter.

Comment: (Bearing in mind that C# generics are actually compiled into the assembly and may be consumed later using types that didn't exist when the generic was authored, leads to different design decisions)

Comment: This is actually a sign of a code smell. And a XY-problem. You are asking us to fix your solution to a certain problem, but your solution is not a good solution. So the **_real_** question is: why do you want this? What are your trying to do? Give context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a static method be overridden in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828271/can-a-static-method-be-overridden-in-c)

Comment: You can't override a static method, you probably need to convert these functions into instance methods

Comment: @Charlieface there's a bigger problem: he/she wants a virtual method with different return type per overload. Without boxing not possible. But like I say: this is just a sign of the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @JHBonarius Not quite true: in `SpecializedFromBaseGeneric : BaseGeneric<int>` an instance method would actually return an `int`, no boxing needed.

Comment: @Charlieface but you cannot get an `int` when called from the base. The OP probably wants to use overloading.

Comment: What does "specialization" mean in this question? The code actually shows overloading. The explanations sound like C++ template specialization in mind. C# doesn't work that way. It may be possible to solve the actual problem in a different way, eg using extension methods or default interface implementation

Comment: [Static abstract interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) could also help. In C# 11 and later operators can be defined as abstract methods in generic interfaces. All numeric .NET 7 types implement addition by implementing the static operators in [System.Numerics.IAdditionOperators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = BaseGeneric<int>.DoStuff()
```

This one calls the function of a base class. It returns new T(), that equals new int(), that equals zero.

```
var result = SpecializedFromBaseGeneric.DoStuff()
```

This one will return what you need.

Comment: I see. But that is not what I want to achieve. I want to make a specialization. I have updated my question a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @codiac what do you mean by specialization? The code actually shows overloading. You may have C++ template specialization in mind. C# doesn't work that way. You'll have to explain what you want because it may be possible in a different way, eg using extension methods or default interface implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class BaseGeneric<T> where T : IConvertible
    {
        public static T DoStuff()
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                return (T)(object)789;
            }

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            {
                return (T)(object)"ss";
            }

            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

However, [as the asnwer here suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601301/13922250), this is brittle, and doesn't cover every possible usage.

Comment: You are [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) this way, thus it's not such a good solution.